# I want to shift the column header down into rows,all the rows gets shifted down by one , what is the precise and short way to do this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to shift the column header down into rows so that the column header comes first on row index and all the rows gets shifted down by one , what is the precise and short way to do this?
[image]

Comment: Hi Kanika, please try posting code snippets next time instead of screenshots. So that if someone wants to reproduce your output, it would be easy to do so. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are reading a csv to generate your dataframe then just use `header=None`

```
pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None)
```

By default, the first row of your csv is interpreted as the header and used as column names.

Answer (score 1):

you should do:

```
 pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.columns, index = df.columns).T, df])
```

This is in case you have the data inplace,

otherwise you can rectify the problem on reading the data into python by declaring the argument `header = None`